# How to add personal icons in Glade without polluting hierarchy

Tags: c, icons, gtk3, glade

I've been looking for solutions for several weeks now, but I'm having a bit of trouble finding and understanding (in cases where I find documentation).

I'm currently developing an application for a school project. But I used a GtkToolPalette (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkToolPalette.html) so that the user can have icons to drag and drop into a drawing area. The problem is that first of all, these icons are very specific to what I want, so I can't find them in the icons that Glade/GTK3 already offers. Second, if I add all the icons one by one in Glade via the buttons on my GtkToolPalette it creates images each time (i.e. a lot) in the hierarchy of my objects, widgets and it completely pollutes my Glade workspace.

Is there a way to make all these additions cleanly. At the moment, I haven't found any method via glade. However, I finally found this https://developer.gnome.org/ThemedIcons/ but I don't really understand the method.

Does anyone know of an effective method?

Thank you in advance for your attention and your answers :)

Comment: @SivaGuru your comment is useless and irrelevant, the problem is perfectly described and doesn't involve any code writing.

Comment: @William what's exactly unclear about themed icons link?

Comment: From what I understood : first of all, you put the images you want on a path. For my part: `/home/william/Programming/S4_PROJECT/APP/icons/hicolor/16x16/actions`.
Then we call: `gtk_icon_theme_append_search_path (gtk_icon_theme_get_default (), "home/william/Programming/S4_PROJECT/APP/icons");` as in example
Finally we try to use the icon : 
`gtk_image_set_from_icon_name(GTK_IMAGE(app.test), "etb-set1", GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);`
Did I understand how that worked? Because it doesn't seem to be working at all :(

Comment: However, this is one of the last links I've found lately and although it's not Glade related at all I may not have done enough testing yet.

Comment: Although it's supposed to be placed in `/usr/share/`, your code *should* work too. I think, the problem is the missing `/` in the beginning of your path.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't come back because a member of my project group and I thought we had found an alternative solution.  But finally we came across a depreciated function and we found ourselves back on the methods that the site I posted talks about. Only, it still doesn't work. So for the moment we've decided to use something much less beautiful I think, here's a preview of it:

Comment: `char icon_path [100];`
    `snprintf(icon_path, sizeof icon_path,
            "icons/actions/%s.ico", icon);`
    `GtkWidget *icon_widget = gtk_image_new_from_file(icon_path);`
    `gtk_tool_button_set_icon_widget(GTK_TOOL_BUTTON(item), icon_widget);`
    `free(icon);`

    `gtk_tool_item_group_insert (GTK_TOOL_ITEM_GROUP (grp), item, -1);`

What's a pity I find from my beginner's point of view, is that you can find a few examples of using functions like `gtk_icon_theme_append_search_path` on the internet.

Comment: So I remain open to any cleaner solution or possible correction of what I said before.